# Approximating the summation of the logarithm of a function

Tags: summation, logarithms, geometric-series

I am working through a textbook for self-study and came across an approximation that I'm unsure how to solve
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \mathrm{ln}[A - (n-1)\epsilon ] = N \mathrm{ln}[A - (N-1)\epsilon/2] + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2}),
$$
where $A$ and $\epsilon$ are positive constants. We can assume $N\epsilon \ll A$. I tried using the [Euler-Maclaurin sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_remainder_term) but I can't get the approximation back. I'm starting to think there's something simple that I missed, perhaps with a geometric summation. Thoughts?

Comment: How large is $A$ compared with $N$? Can we assume that $N\epsilon/A \to 0$?

Comment: @martycohen It's not explicitly stated but I believe so, yes

Comment: I did some fiddling - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite our sum as a product, using [this equation from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_product#Connection_to_indefinite_sum).

$$\prod_n{f(n)} = \exp\left( \sum_n{( \log{f(n)} )} \right) \tag{1}$$
$$\sum_n{( \log{f(n)} )} = \ln{ \left( \prod_n{f(n)} \right) } \tag{2}$$

So we get

$$\ln{ \left( \prod_n{ \ln[A-(n-1)\epsilon] } \right) } \tag{3}$$
$$\ln{ \Big(  \ln[A-0\epsilon] \cdot \ln[A-1\epsilon]\cdots \ln[A-(N-1)\epsilon]  \Big) } \tag{4}$$
$$\ln{ \Big(  \ln \Big[(A-0\epsilon) + (A-1\epsilon) + \dots + (A-(N-1)\epsilon) \Big] \Big) } \tag{5}$$
$$\ln{ \left(  \ln \left[ NA-\frac{N^2+N}{2}\epsilon - N\epsilon/2 \right] \right) } \tag{6}$$
$$\ln{ \left( \log{(N)}\epsilon/2 + \ln \left[ \frac{A}{\epsilon/2}-N \right] \right) } \tag{7}$$
$$\epsilon/2 + \ln{ \left( \log{(N)} + \ln \left[ \frac{A-N \epsilon/2}{(\epsilon/2)^2}\right] \right) } \tag{8}$$
$$\epsilon/2 + \ln{ \left( \log{(N)} + \ln \left[ A-N \epsilon/2\right] + O((\epsilon/2)^2)\right) } \tag{9}$$
$$O((\epsilon/2)^2) + \ln{ \left( \log{(N)} + \ln \left[ A-N \epsilon/2\right] \right) } \tag{9}$$
$$O((\epsilon/2)^2) + \ln{ \left( \ln \left[ (A-N \epsilon/2\right)^N] \right) } \tag{10}$$

Now we can reverse the operation we did between (2) and (3) to get

$$O((\epsilon/2)^2) + \sum_{n=1}^N{ \ln \left[ A-N \epsilon/2 \right] } \tag{11}$$
$$N \ln \left[ A-N \epsilon/2 \right] + O(\epsilon^2) \tag{12}$$

This wasn't obvious to me!

Comment: Thank you for working on this! Very clever

Answer (score 1):

Here's some naive fiddling.

Writing $c$ for $\epsilon$
because lazy,
using $=\ln(1-c)=-c+O(c^2)$,
and assuming that $c \to 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \ln[A - (n-1)c ] 
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} (\ln(A)+\ln[1 - (n-1)c/A ]\\ 
&=N\ln(A)+\sum_{n=1}^{N} \ln(1 - (n-1)c/A)\\ 
&=N\ln(A)-\sum_{n=1}^{N} ((n-1)c/A+O(c^2)))\\ 
&=N\ln(A)-N(N-1)c/(2A)+O(Nc^2)
\qquad\text{assuming the big-oh is uniform}\\ 
&=N(\ln(A)-(N-1)c/(2A))+O(Nc^2)\\
&\approx N(\ln(A)+\ln(1-(N-1)c/(2A))+O(Nc^2)\\
&= N(\ln(A(1-(N-1)c/(2A)))+O(Nc^2)\\
&= N(\ln(A-(N-1)c/2))+O(Nc^2)\\
\end{array}
$